# Terraform isn't reading security group IDs from remote state

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group, terragrunt

My terraform module does not read a remote state data source if I use interpolation.

This works:

**security_group_ids = [data.terraform_remote_state.sg.outputs.sg_paris_id]**

And when I run terragrunt apply it lists the SG ID but it makes the module pointless as I have to make a module for each VPCE I want to create

This does not work:

**security_group_ids = ["data.terraform_remote_state.sg.outputs.sg_${local.city}_id"]**

Terragrunt prints "data.terraform_remote_state.sg.outputs.sg_${local.city}_id" in the new plan and returns an error saying it expects 'sg- something' when I apply.

I think it's because security_group_ids is expecting a set not a string, but 'toset' doesn't have any impact.

I'm using TF 0.12.28 and TG 0.23.24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using string interpolation correctly. You are really just creating a string with the value: `"data.terraform_remote_state.sg.outputs.sg_paris.id"`. At no point are you telling Terraform to actually take that string and lookup the value represented by the data source with that name.

You're going to need to use the Terraform [lookup](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/lookup) function to accomplish what you are trying to do. There might be a cleaner way to do this in Terraform 1, but not in the old 0.12 version you are running.

```
security_group_ids = [lookup(data.terraform_remote_state.sg.outputs, "sg_${local.city}_id", null)]
```

Comment: Mark you're a genius, this has worked. Thank you so very much.